# How to hide the rest of unused image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

more you ask, more knowledge you get. Right ? I don't know this question is basic or not but a little make me think hard.

Look `pic 1` what do i have.

pic 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAQEo.jpg

When i upload an image, it will show up to the container called `<img id="image"/>` and the image is horizontally draggable. My problem is, how do i hide the rest of unused image ? When i dragging the image, the rest will not showing up

Comment: Please don't downvote this :(

Comment: DV wasn't mine, but I would guess it's because you didn't include your HTML in the question, which would have been useful.

Comment: Someone like you have more intelegent than someone who unvoted this post, I think u could understand even html code isn't included. @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 1):

To fix this you can place `overflow: hidden` in the CSS of the parent element of the `#image` element.

Answer (score 1):

Add the style overflow: hidden; to the parent element, like this:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <img src="img.png" id="image" />
</div>
```